# Automate VIM EDITOR and update values using shell script (similar to editing crontab via shell script)

Tags: vim, chef-infra

I am trying to automate a VI edit for a command similar to crontab editing via Shell script but not working for me so far.

Here is the final json with admin as true:

```
'{"name":"SQLSRVR","admin":"true","json_class":"Chef::ApiClient","chef_type":"client"}'
```

As you can see the EDITOR environment variable has to be set or passed as command line option -e

```
[root@vrhost user]# knife client edit SQLSRVR
ERROR: RuntimeError: Please set EDITOR environment variable

[root@vrhost user]# knife client edit
USAGE: knife client edit CLIENT (options)
-s, --server-url URL             Chef Server URL
-k, --key KEY                    API Client Key
    --[no-]color                 Use colored output, defaults to enabled
-c, --config CONFIG              The configuration file to use
    --defaults                   Accept default values for all questions
-d, --disable-editing            Do not open EDITOR, just accept the data as is
-e, --editor EDITOR              Set the editor to use for interactive commands
-E, --environment ENVIRONMENT    Set the Chef environment
-F, --format FORMAT              Which format to use for output
-u, --user USER                  API Client Username
    --print-after                Show the data after a destructive operation
-V, --verbose                    More verbose output. Use twice for max verbosity
-v, --version                    Show chef version
-y, --yes                        Say yes to all prompts for confirmation
-h, --help                       Show this message
FATAL: You must specify a client name
```

The below command opens a vim editor for editing to make the change from ["admin": "false"] to ["admin": "true"]:

```
[root@vrhost user]# knife client edit SQLSRVR -e vim 

{
  "name": "SQLSRVR",
  "admin": false,
  "json_class": "Chef::ApiClient",
  "chef_type": "client",
}
```

I am trying to do this through a shell script and would like to automate it and tried many options but had no luck so far.

```
[root@vrhost ~]# (echo ^[:g/false/s/false/true/^[:wq!^M) | knife client edit SQLSRVR -e vim
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
Object unchanged, not saving
```

or

```
[root@vrhost user]# echo (^[echo     '{"name":"SQLSRVR","admin":"true","json_class":"Chef::ApiClient","chef_type":"client"}'^[:w    q!^M) | knife client edit SQLSRVR -e

[root@vrhost ~]# knife client show SQLSRVR
admin:       false
chef_type:   client
json_class:  Chef::ApiClient
name:        SQLSRVR
```

this is very similar to automating crontab editing via shell script but this has not been working for me.

Comment: I saw something similar on this site [link](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/shell-scripting/threads/166819/how-do-i-edit-crontab-using-a-script)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but wouldn't you be better using `sed` rather than trying to automate `vi`?

Comment: cdarke - this is similar problem to crontab editing via shell script (using vi). yes alternatives can be done by saving as a temp file and then loading it but in this case the command is expecting an editor and I am not very familiar with its workings and trying to emulate editing via vi from a shell script

Comment: Ingo - trying that solution let me see if it works but the issue I have is similar to the crontab editing. See the solution provided by eggi - http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/shell-scripting/threads/166819/how-do-i-edit-crontab-using-a-script

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you really need special Vim capabilities, you're probably better off using non-interactive tools like `sed`, `awk`, or Perl / Python / Ruby / *your favorite scripting language here*.

That said, you can use Vim non-interactively, using *silent batch mode*.

```
vim -T dumb --noplugin -n -es -S "commands.ex" "filespec"
```

Instead of the external script to read the commands from via `-S "commands.ex"`, you can also give a few commands directly via `-c cmd1 -c cmd2`. See `:help -s-ex` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Check out

```
$ knife client edit --help
[...]
-d, --disable-editing            Do not open EDITOR, just accept the data as is
```

So I guess you can change the values without editing in vim. Just:

- get the client data in json format.
- replace needed values with sed.
- upload the data from file.

Code:

```
$ knife client show -Fj SQLSRVR > SQLSRVR.json
$ sed -i.old "s/\"admin\": true,/\"admin\": false,/" SQLSRVR.json
$ knife client edit -d SQLSRVR < SQLSRVR.json
```

Something like that.

Comment: Same for me, I trying to do same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31744371/object-unchanged-when-running-knife-client-edit

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links to references:

i) http://mirror.hep.wisc.edu/stable/chef/chef-server-webui/app/controllers/clients_controller.rb

ii) http://www.rubydoc.info/github/opscode/chef/master/Shell/Extensions - tried but unable to get it to work

Finally did the following (it does give 409 the 2nd time on call and I did not need to do it a 2nd time):

```
# call to below rb, CLIENTNAME is the name of the client and STATE is true/false
$ knife exec clienttransform.rb CLIENTNAME STATE

$ cat clienttransform.rb

Chef::Config[:solo] = false

class Company
  class TransformClient

    attr_accessor :clientname
    attr_accessor :isclientadmin

    def initialize(client_name, is_client_admin)
      @clientname = client_name
      @isclientadmin = is_client_admin
    end

    def transform
      client=Chef::ApiClient.load(@clientname)
      # puts "client.name : " + client.name
      # puts "client.admin : " + client.admin.to_s
      # puts "XX - clientname : " + @clientname
      # puts "XX - isclientadmin : " + @isclientadmin.to_s
      boolisclientadmin = !!@isclientadmin
      client.admin(boolisclientadmin)
      client.save()
    end

  end

end

client_name = ARGV[2].to_s()
is_client_admin = ARGV[3].to_s()

# puts "YY - client_name : " + client_name
# puts "YY - is_client_admin : " + is_client_admin

trc = Company::TransformClient.new(client_name, is_client_admin)
trc.transform

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set your editor and it will work. In my case I use vim editor that's why my command was as follows:

```
export EDITOR=vim
```