# Object unchanged when running knife client edit

Tags: bash, shell, chef-infra, knife

I'm running `knife client edit` command to edit a node in Chef to set admin permissions. I would like to do this programmatically so my intention is to add this command to a shell script if I can make it work.

The previous state of the node is (**UPDATE**):

```
$ knife client show -Fj my_node
{
  "name": "my_node",
  "public_key": "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n...key...\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n",
  "validator": false,
  "admin": false,
  "json_class": "Chef::ApiClient",
  "chef_type": "client"
}
```

When running the command it says that the object is unchanged and after checking the node with `knife client` I can 
verify that still has the admin attribute set to false:

```
$ knife client edit -d my_node < my_node.json
Object unchanged, not saving
```

The content of `my_node.json` file is:

```
{
  "name": "my_node",
  "public_key": "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n...key...\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n",
  "validator": false,
  "admin": true,
  "json_class": "Chef::ApiClient",
  "chef_type": "client"
}
```

I don't know how to make this piece work. 
Any help on this will be very much appreciated.

NOTE: 
    $ knife --version
    Chef: 12.2.1

**UPDATE:** I couldn't find an accepted answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941296/automate-vim-editor-and-update-values-using-shell-script-similar-to-editing-cro) which is quite similar.

**UPDATE 2:** I tried these other ways as well with no luck at all (using same json file):

```
$ cat my_node.json | knife client edit my_node -d
Object unchanged, not saving

$ knife client edit my_node -d < my_node.json
Object unchanged, not saving
```

Comment: One thing I noticed from the man page was the argument order is different in your example. What if you try `knife client edit my_node -d < my_node.json` instead? Additionally, it isn't clear to me that it feeding it data with `<` is the way to do that... have you tried `cat my_node.json | knife client edit my_node -d`?

Comment: Also, it doesn't look like you're actually editing anything. You're wholesale replacing; maybe `knife node from file my_node.json` would be better?

Comment: Running those commands you've told I get exactly same output: Object unchanged, not saving

Comment: I'm just wondering now if the input file should be a JSON file, man page says nothing about the format.

Comment: The input file should be identical in format to the output of `knife node show -Fjson <node name>`. Are you sure the file is different from what's already on the server?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure since I used the output from knife client show, replaced a boolean value from false to true, and then use that file for knife cilent edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84823/discussion-between-scratte-and-martin).

Answer (score 1):

If you already got the file with the content you need, there is a trick to use it.

```
knife client edit -e "cp my_node.json"
```

Explanation on how interactive editing works on an app (knife in this case):

1. The app starts on foreground the command on EDITOR environment variable passing a temporary file as argument
2. When the command ends, the app opens the temporary file and uses it

So if all you want is changing a word, you can use sed instead:

```
knife client edit -e "sed -i  's/\"admin\":\s*false/\"admin\": true/'"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between your my_node.json and your my_node settings. Change a value and try again.

Comment: The OP had already confirmed in the comments that the file _is_ different.

Comment: What is the difference then? Looking at the code in his question they are identical, and the behavior of the knife command agrees with me. 

To confirm they are identical I copy/pasted the content of the first into Atom, then hit control-f and copy/pasted the second one's content into the find parameter. 

If the actual case doesn't match what OP posted then OP needs to update the question. If it does then OP made the mistake of trying to update the file with itself, which knife rightly ignored in keeping with idempotent philosophy.

Comment: Perhaps the most constructive thing to do would be to ask the OP :)

Comment: Sorry guys, I had to update my question cause I copied the previous state of the node after I changed the admin flag manually to true using the editor during some testing. I could find a way to do not require admin permissions set in the nodes but the question is still open if another users are running with the same issue.